# Execute a function after the array is complete - Swift

Tags: swift

I'm wanting to execute a function after an Array is completely set. I tried to implement didSet in the declaration of the array, but the code inside of it is called each time an element is added to the array. Is there any way to do what I want?
Here is some of my code:

```
var arrayScore = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] {
    didSet {
        for i in 0..<arrayScore.count {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(Int(arrayScore[i]), forKey: "arrayScore\(i)")
        }
        LineGraphView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

Comment: What does *is completely set* mean?

Comment: Adding all seven elements. So they are greater than zero

Comment: I know that the array has values. but i want those values to be different from zero before the function is executed

Comment: Why would you set `arrayScore.count` different entries in UserDefaults, if you could just set the whole array as an entry

Comment: Because i'm having trouble obtaining those values as int if a do so. I know is not ideal, but for now it does work.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to `filter` the items whose value is zero. If the result array is empty all values are non-zero

```
if arrayScore.filter({ $0 == 0.0 }).isEmpty {
    print("every value in the array is > 0.0")
}
```

or – as mentioned by Sulthan  – more efficient with `contains`

```
if !arrayScore.contains(0.0) {
    print("every value in the array is > 0.0")
}
```

However if you want to check if the sum of the items is not zero use

```
if arrayScore.reduce(0.0, + ) != 0.0 {
    print("at least one value in the array is not zero")
}
```

Comment: `filter { }.isEmpty` is generally expressed using `contains`, .e.g `!contains(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var arrayScore = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] {
    didSet {
        for i in 0..<arrayScore.count {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(Int(arrayScore[i]), forKey: "arrayScore\(i)")
            if(i == (arrayScore.count - 1)){
                LineGraphView.setNeedsDisplay()
            }
        }
    }
}
```